# Can't connect File's owner to View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a `ViewController.h` and `ViewController.m` and a `MyViewController.xib` file.

Now I would like to create a new xib with this name: `MyViewController_47.xib` for the iPhone 6.

After I created the new xib file, I set the `File's Owner` to `ViewController` and I don't see that the View outlet.

My `ViewController.h` was inherited from `BaseViewController` which is inherited from `GAITrackedViewController`

I really don't know how to connect the View to `File's Owner`.

Comment: check once name s added properly or not

Comment: I have already checked the name because I clicked on the grey arrow on the right side, and xcode load the ViewController.h file
I have already clean the project, reopen xcode, restart the mac...

Comment: one .m to two xib？

Comment: yes, I load the correct xib for the optimal screen size

Answer (score 3):

Select your nib file **MyViewController_47.xib** -> File's Owner -> In side panel select 3rd option (3rd tab) -> Custom Class (class -> your view controller name).

[Follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU0VM.png)

If this doesn't work then re-name your ViewController to NewViewController and try the same process.